# Php form values with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm struggling trying to create a **form in php** and get the values with a $_POST, sounds easy but my problem is the "path" of the php file.

**Example :** Index.php -> include text.php -> include form.php

When I click "submit" in the form I cannot get anything because the web goes to "self" which is not form.php, it's index.php !!

Anyone knows how to submit a form a do nothing? just store the field values in $_POST['name'], for instance.

Maybe if I put an "isset" in index.php and another one in text.php ? have to be something easier.

Can I get the $_POST in ajax for instance ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I don't have any idea what your asking. What do you mean with for example: `he web goes to "self" which is not form.php, it's index.php`?

Comment: Hi @wumm , using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] I can send a form to the same page, so far so good; using action='' goes nowhere, but... if the php page it's not the root doesn't work.  My web loads a index.php which depending the logged user include one php or other... and then again for the sections...so when I'm on index.php showing the form.php the form doesn't work because goes to the root which is index.php.

Comment: That's what happens when you are trying to learn and skip the basics.. How is your html form set? Where the action attribute points to?

Comment: Hi @enapupe, I tried action="" and action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>", but nothing.

Comment: @Olderdais, you'll want to set the action="" to wherever you want the POST data to GO. For example, if your form is on index.php, and you want to submit the form and go to the next page and display your form (POST) data there, you'll want to set the action="form.php". Additionally, please reword your question, it'll make it much more clear.